# Perl if statement never true, even though conditions are true

Tags: perl, if-statement

$band1 and $band2 two are declared as (with $band1 on the left and $band2 on the right)

```
s12 t12
s21 s11
t12 s12
t15 t23
t23 t15
```

After the first print statement I get

```
s   12  t   12
s   21  s   11
t   12  s   12
t   15  t   23
t   23  t   15
```

But it seems as if my second if statement is never executed(as in should it the second time through. It looks correct to me though I don't know why it's not executing, it should print hello the second time, third time and fourth time through. Really it should print hello any time band and two are both t's and band 1's number is higher than band 2's or band 1 and 2 are both s's and band 2's number is higher than band 1's, or if the band on the left is a t and the band on the right is a s.

```
my @splitB1 = split(//, "$band1");
my @splitB2 = split(//, "$band2");
my $band1Num = join("","$splitB1[1]","$splitB1[2]");
my $band2Num = join("","$splitB2[1]","$splitB2[2]");
print $splitB1[0], "\t", $band1Num, "\t", $splitB2[0], "\t", $band2Num, "\n";
if (($band1Num < $band2Num and $splitB1[0]=="s" and $splitB2[0]=="s"){
       print "Hello World"
 }
```

Thank-you

Comment: Use `==` for numerical comparison, but use `eq` for string comparision:  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators

Comment: Your code has a syntax error. And quoting single variables like `"$band1"` or `"$splitB1[1]"` is unnecessary and makes it harder to read. Could you show us what is typically in `$band1` and `$band2`?

Comment: Always `use warnings 'all';` (and `use strict;` if you aren't already). That would have warned you about `==` being for numeric comparisons as Miller explained.

Comment: This can't be the running code, because there is a syntax error of unbalanced parentheses on the `if` statement. But even removing the extra left paren, the `if` logic is not as your text describes! The `if` condition says that only if 1st number is *less than* 2nd number *and* first letter is `s` *and* second letter is `s` will the `print` be reached. *None* of your data lines meets that strict condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The immediate problem is [`==` is used for numeric equality and `eq` is used for string equality](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators). These are different operations, so Perl has separate string and numeric operators. Some other languages can guess what you mean by `==`, but Perl variables lack types so it cannot.

With warnings on (`use warnings`) you'll get a warning.

```
s   11  t   12
Argument "s" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at /Users/schwern/tmp/test.plx line 13.
Argument "s" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at /Users/schwern/tmp/test.plx line 13.
Argument "s" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at /Users/schwern/tmp/test.plx line 13.
Argument "t" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at /Users/schwern/tmp/test.plx line 13.
Hello World
```

The condition is true because when Perl tries to force the letters `s` or `t` or anything that doesn't look like a number to be a number it uses `0`. `0 == 0` so `$splitB1[0] == "s"` is true.

---

### Other issues...

***Don't quote single variables***. It makes the code harder to read and in some cases with overloaded objects (ie. objects acting like they're strings) it can cause subtle bugs by prematurely turning the object into a string.

```
join("",$splitB1[1],$splitB1[2]);      # Yes
join("","$splitB1[1]","$splitB1[2]");  # NO
```

***Use a regex, not split***. This is not an appropriate use of split. Your code relies on the incoming string to only have one letter and two digits. It's faster, less code, and more robust to use a regex to look for letters followed by numbers.

```
my($code1, $num1) = $band1 = /([a-z]+)(\d+)/i;
```

***Use an array or hash rather than $var1 and $var2***. Any time you find yourself writing `$var1` and `$var2` consider using an array instead. `$var[0]` and `$var[1]`. It's easier to pass them around as a group, and you can loop over them saving repeating code.

Putting it all together, plus a few other touches like using [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) and spacing out complex conditions...

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @bands = qw(s11 s12);

my @codes;
my @nums;

for my $idx (0..1) {
    ($codes[$idx], $nums[$idx]) = $bands[$idx] =~ /([a-z]+)(\d+)/i;
}

say $codes[0], "\t", $nums[0], "\t", $codes[1], "\t", $nums[1];

if (
    $nums[0] < $nums[1] and
    $codes[0] eq "s"    and
    $codes[1] eq "s"
) {
    say "Hello World"
}
```

This does not match the logic you described, but the code already had that problem. I leave that for you to figure out from here. (Hint: [`xor`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-or-and-Exclusive-Or), exclusive or, or the way humans mean "or", might help here).

Comment: Ok well I know I didn't specifically say what's wrong with my logic, but that was all I wanted, the only reason I posted was to figure out what was wrong with my logic

Comment: @schwem Just I wasn't asking to make my code cleaner, I was asking how can I fix my if statement so that it evaluates to true

Comment: You kind just posted some code that does the same thing as mine that I'm unfamiliar with

Comment: I posted an answer to your most obvious problem. I also posted some not immediately obvious extra cleanups with explanation. It's a bonus; even if you don't understand it now, it points to what you might learn next. Coding is more than just getting the desired output, and Stack Overflow is not a "fix my code for free" service. If you have questions about the answer, please ask them.

Comment: I'm just unfamiliar with it and if I still can't get the output I need it's easier for me to fiddle the code I wrote that I do understand, but I didn't need to know any of this stuff posted, I just needed to know why my if statement was evaluating to false.

Comment: @C.Monster "*I didn't need to know any of this stuff*"... part of asking an expert is that the expert knows things you don't know that you don't know (not a typo) and can see things you can't. And, again, it's clearly separated from the main part of the answer (which spells out the main bug) so you can ignore it if you like. Now, you can talk about what trouble you're still having and I can try to help. Or you can complain again about your free, expert code review and I'll delete the answer if it's that galling to you.

Comment: Well the only help  I need is my if stament to evaluate to true, I realize half o f it got cut off so the expected output doesn't make sense,  but if that bracket were in there I would still want the second line of input (s21 s11) to eavaluate to true and I don't know why it isn't
And it's just that the only answer I need is getting the if statement to evaluate to true, and I can't figure out why it's not, that's the only thing I'm wondering and I've noticed that if it looks like it's already answered then people won't leave other answers

Comment: @C.Monster [It does evaluate to true for me](https://gist.github.com/schwern/c03f419ece50cdf24e975c5fb39d291e), even with the `==` bug, if `$band1 = 's11'` and `$band2 = 's12'`. Are you sure you're not missing the `Hello World` because there's no newline at the end of the `print`? (this is why I switched to [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html))

Comment: @C.Monster According to your rules, `s21 s11` should be (and is) false. "*or band 1 and 2 are both s's and band 2's number is higher than band 1's*". They're both `s`, but 11 is not higher than 21. False. And don't worry, people will continue to answer if the question is clear and the answers are not complete.